# removing one object from nsarray removes all

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an nsarray of distinct nsmutablearray's called: playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots.  At the beginning of the code below the array contains 6 objects.

```
NSArray *anArray2 = [playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots objectAtIndex:index];
playerSkills = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anArray2];
[playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots removeObject:anArray2];
```

When I step through past the final line above, the array contains 0 objects.  Can anyone explain to me why this might be.  Note that there are no duplicate entries in the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason why this could happen is if all objects of your `playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots` array are the same array. This is a common mistake - it happens when you add the same array object to a mutable array in a loop while setting up your `playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots` array, for example, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    // add some objects, then...
    [playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots addObject:tmp];
    [tmp removeAllObjects]; // Prepare to the new cycle
}
```

You can fix this problem by making a copy of arrays that you put into `playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots`.

Another problem with the `removeObject:` method is that it removes from the array all objects that are equal the one being removed, not just the first instance. If there is a possibility of your `playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots` array storing objects that are equal to each other, switch to using the `removeObjectAtIndex:` method instead.

Comment: This was my first thought, but playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots NSMutableArray * 0x07e352d0 contains: [0] id 0x161040f0, [1] id 0x07ea5440, [2] id 0x07ea75c0, [3] id 0x161e8440, [4] id 0x1615f000, [5] id 0x07ee50a0

Comment: In fact, I do make copies of each array that goes into the container array.

Comment: @NaseivaKhan Could it be that all arrays are equal to each other? (I am not sure if it would make much difference, because I never tried comparing `NSArray`s for equality) Also why do you prefer `removeObject` to `removeObjectAtIndex`?

Comment: @NaseivaKhan do those objects equal each other (maybe empty arrays?) % p (int) [playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots[0] isEqual:playerSkillsByLevelSnapshots[1]]

Comment: @Grady Player: The arrays in fact do equal each other (containing 34 nsnumbers each) so that when one array is released, it transmits release to each of its nsnumbers, which subsequently causes there containers to deallocate, being autoreleased objects.  Thanks.  I will just use mutablecopy to gain ownership.

Comment: @NaseivaKhan I am not sure if your description of what's happening is accurate. I think that `removeObject` goes through an array of equal arrays, removing all objects, because they appear equal to the one being removed. I think that switching to `removeObjectAtIndex` would work better for you.

Comment: @NaseivaKhan listen to dasblinkenlight... I think your thoughts about ownership are getting mixed up with the concept of the array of arrays, and matching values... you seem to be expecting one to be removed, if that is the case you should use `-removeObjectAtIndex`.

Comment: I tried it and it works.  On thinking about about it, you are obviously correct, because an array retains each of its members, not vice versa.  Answer accepted.